# Is it possible to create multiple model instances from a list of lists derived from another model?

Tags: django

I have two models, RecurringEvent and Event. The RecurringEvent models basic purpose is to create a list of datetimes, that is then to be used to create multiple events in the Event model.

I have tried the save method with a for loop. However, no new Events are created, nor are any errors given. I’m not sure if its related to my loop (probably is). I’ve tried it a few different ways (using a list of named tuples, plain list of lists, rewriting the for loop in different ways) and have been unsuccessful. Is a model.manager needed to do this?

I appreciate any help and would definitely like to know of any better ways to go about this.

models.py

```
class ReccuringEvent(models.Model):
    semester_start = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    semester_end = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    lesson_start = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    lesson_end = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    …
    start_list = [d.combine(d.date(), self.lesson_start) for d in semester_lessons]
    end_list = [d.combine(d.date(), self.lesson_end) for d in semester_lessons]

    startend_list = list(zip(start_list, end_list))

    recurring_event_list = []
    for d in range(len(startend_list)):
        templist=[]
        templist.append(self.title)
        templist.append(startend_list[d][0])
        templist.append(startend_list[d][1])
        recurring_event_list.append(templist)


    recurring_event_list_namedtuple = namedtuple('event', ['title', 'start', 'end'])
    recurring_event_list_named = [recurring_event_list_namedtuple(*d) for d in recurring_event_list]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         for d in range(len(recurring_event_list_named)):
             Event.objects.create(recurring_event_list_named)
             super().save(*args, **kwargs) # have tried including super(Event, self)…

class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `recurring_event_list`?

Comment: Did you debug it? Add `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` before your for loop in your save() method and see what's going on.

Comment: @CalebGoodman I edited my post and included the code that you asked for. Thanks for taking a look.